# how do you use setCurrentTab

Tags: java, android, tabs

How do you use the setCurrentTab command ? this is the code I have for it right now... When I debug it I get "C: Tab 3" so the saving aspect is working fine but the tab still isnt changing? any help for me? Thanks!

```
TabHost th = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

        th.setup();
        TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        specs.setIndicator("Zone Manager");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        specs.setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_vaccontrol));
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        specs.setIndicator("Tab 3");
        th.addTab(specs);

        Tab = (settings.getInt("Tab", 1));
        Log.d("TabStuff", "C: Tab " + Tab);
        th.setCurrentTab(Tab);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `setCurrentTabByTag(String nameOfTheTabSpec)` method instead the simple setCurrentTab

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following [the Android developers guide](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html). It's really helpful even if you aren't going to use a `TabActivity`. Could you post the XML for `R.id.tabX`?